# template class as template arguments in another class

Tags: c++, class, templates

So here is a question I could not get an answer to, even after searching this website (and others) for the last two days.

For the sake of argument, lets assume that I wanted to create two template classes *a* and *b*. Class *a* is just a user defined datatype, say a vector or matrix, so I can overload different operators and make working with these special datatype easier. Class *b* is going to take class *a* as a template parameter (which can be thought of a 2D field of vectors or whatever datatype *a* represents) and both class *a* and *b* should be declared in a *header* file but implemented in a *.cpp* file.

**EDIT:** I am aware what that templates are limited, in the sense that we have to implement them in *header* files. But I am also aware that we can define explicit template argument at compile time (if we know which template arguments will be taken) and then split the implementation into *header* and *.cpp* files. This works fine if my template arguments are standard c++ types such as float, doubles or int but I don't know how to proceed when the template argument is a class with template parameters itself, see the following code with explanations.

In code form, this would loke something like this

a.h

```
template<class T>
class a {
    public:
        a(T);
    private:
        T data;
};
```

a.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "a.h"

// explicit template declaration
template class a<double>;

template<class T>
a<T>::a(T in) {
    data = in;
}
```

b.h

```
template< class T>
class b {
    public:
        b(T);
    private:
        T item;
};
```

b.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "b.h"

// explicit template template declaration
template class b<double>;

template<class T>
b<T>::b(T in) {
    item = in;
}
```

and finally *main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

int main() {
    a<double>    foo(3);   // this works
    b<a<double>> bar(foo); // this doesn't
    return 0;
}
```

when I compile and run the above I get

```
main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `b<a<double> >::b(a<double>)'
```

I have been tinkering with the code for a while, I know the issue is with the *b* class. I have tried using

```
template<template<class> class T>
```

instead of

```
template<class T>
```

which I think should be the correct usage (or in a similar form) but then I am getting issues with the explicit template declaration in the *b.cpp* file and this is only as far as my template understanding goes.

Any ideas which changes should be made to *b.cpp* and *b.h* to make this minimal example work?

Comment: I am not sure why this has been marked as duplicate, the suggested post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) is related but not answering my problem. If you look at my a.h and a.cpp file, you will see that I am already declaring my templates explicitly so I don't get a compilation error (see also the main.cpp file where it is indicated that this is working). My problem is with using a template class as a template argument in another class, i.e. using class a as a template argument in class b (again, indicated in main.cpp).

Comment: No, you can't put `b<T>::b` in a separate translation unit from places that use it. It's not a compiler error, but a linker error

Comment: Aren't you just missing `template class b<a<double>>;`?

Comment: @Quentin cheers, that solved the problem ... seems so obvious but i was apparently looking in a different area (template template arguments), didn't realise the solution was that simple, thanks again!